# Custom multi-step Google forms

Tags: google-drive-api, google-forms

I've done a couple of custom Google forms, where you plunk the `<form>...</form>` into your own file. They submit just fine.

I cant figure out how to apply this to a multi-step or multi-page form. The only solution I can think of is to build it as a giant single form, and `.show()` and `.hide()` the necessary bits to make it appear as a multi-step. This is obviously far from ideal.

Does anyone have a real solution to this?

Here's the expanded explanation of the `<form>...</form>` that I mentioned before:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var submitted=false;</script>
<iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none;" onload="if(submitted) {window.location='thanks.html';}"></iframe>
<form action="YOUR-GOOGLE-FORM-ACTION-URL" method="post" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="submitted=true;" class="custom eight columns" id="ss-form">
    <label>
    <input>...
    <input type="submit" ....>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a Google Form for this? http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=87809

Google Forms lets you create, share and embed forms on other pages, and the responses feed into a Google Spreadsheet that you can access via Google Drive.

This will also allow you to create custom Form paths that will take users to different places based on form feedback:

> **Split questions into multiple pages**
>
> If you've created a long form, for example, and would like to make it
>   easier for your respondents to fill it out, you can add page breaks.
>   From the Add item drop-down menu, select Page break.

Once you create the page break you will need to make a form question/answer take an action to "jump" to that particular page break.

This page will be helpful in providing targets for your page breaks: http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=141062&topic=1360904&ctx=topic

> **Page navigation and how to embed a form**
>
> If you've added page breaks to
>   a form, you can add different sets of questions based on a previous
>   answer within the form, and allow people to skip irrelevant sections.
>
> Multiple choice questions with the 'Go to page based on answer' option
>   enabled direct form respondents to particular pages based on their
>   answer, whereas page navigation automatically routes form respondents
>   to a specific page based on your selection. For example, you can
>   create a form asking your respondents to select their language and
>   then direct them to questions written in their language. Then, they
>   can all be automatically routed back to the same page using page
>   navigation in page breaks.

Comment: it is a Google form right now. When the form was created in Google, it was built as a multi-step form.

Answer (score 1):

I have also been looking around to solve this issue.

The most comprehensive tutorial I found here: http://morning.am/tutorials/how-to-style-google-forms-redux/ from Dillon. Yet it contains heavy manual customization every time you change your form. Something more convenient would be a javascript that does exactly that for you, I think there is someone selling just a script like that somewhere on the web.

Another promising possibility would have been by Google itself via their google app script platform: http://www.jellybend.com/2013/01/15/create-custom-forms-with-gui-builder-and-google-apps-script/ With this option one is at least sure to comply with google's allowed usage guidelines. Yet it has been DEPRECATED. Bummer.